# How to turn off Spotify shuffle? I do not have a premium account

Tags: spotify

I'd like to know if I can make Spotify's shuffle shuffle according to the range I set in advance. In other words, it's not 100% shuffle. If possible, does this require membership? Or are there any tools that can assist?

Comment: Please note this site is about recommending *software,* not assets or [resources](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2470/185) like [howtos](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/882/185), [manuals/tutorials](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1258/185), etc. As your question includes asking for tools, please **[edit]** it to be more precise, focusing on that. See [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) for what is essential in this concern. Thanks!